# calculate Levenshtein Distance for web click stream data

Tags: distance-functions, distance, similarities

I want to calculate Levenshtein Distance between to web click paths. I have a web page list around 500.

```
user id     path
1  abc,cde,eg,ba
2     abc,cde,ba
3   abc,yz,zx,eg
4  abc,cde,eg,ba
5        abc,cde
6            abc
7      cde,eg,ba
```

I converted this in to integer list like following.

```
id  path
1  1234
2   124
3  1563
4  1234
5    12
6     1
7   234
```

But the problem with my situation is I have 500 web pages. How to differentiate page 3 and 7 and 37? Is there more elegant way to convert this?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with this?

Comment: @Dimitriy V. Masterov: I want find the similarity of web click sequences?

Answer (score 1):

You could assign an ID to each page. Then store the paths as,

UserID FromPage ToPage

That way you can reconstruct the paths, but also quickly calculate how many paths go through a page and some other magnitudes